# How to force set all the text-color of my `<a>` to be different ?

Tags: css

### Details

- I want to force set all the text-color of my `<a>` to be different.
- For some reasons, it won't take effect.

### What I have tried

```
<ul id="sticky" class="sticklr">
    <?php foreach(array_unique(array_values($continent)) as $continent_id){
        if($continent_id == 1 ){ $continent_name = "Europe" ; $continent_code = "EU" ;  
        }elseif ($continent_id == 2 ){ $continent_name = "Asia" ; $continent_code = "AS" ;    
        }elseif ($continent_id == 3 ){ $continent_name = "North America" ; $continent_code = "NA" ;    
        }elseif ($continent_id == 4 ){ $continent_name = "Oceania" ; $continent_code = "OC" ;   
        }elseif ($continent_id == 5 ){ $continent_name = "South America" ; $continent_code = "SA" ;   
        }else{  $continent_name = "Africa" ; $continent_code = "AF" ; }  ?>
        <li>
            <a href="#<?php echo $continent_name ?>" class="sticky-<?php echo $continent_code ?>">
            <?php echo $continent_name ?> | <?php echo $continent_code ?>
            </a>
        </li>
        <?php }?>
    </ul>
```

- Note : the path is like this :

  .sticklr > li > a .sticky-`continent_code`{
      //CSS Code ; 
   }

`CSS`

```
.sticklr > li > a .sticky-AS{

    color: orange !important;
    text-decoration: none !important;
}
.sticklr > li > a .sticky-EU{

    color: #50c0de !important;
    text-decoration: none !important;
}
.sticklr > li > a .sticky-NA{

    color: red !important;
    text-decoration: none !important;
}
.sticklr > li > a .sticky-OC{

    color: #428bca !important;
    text-decoration: none !important;
}
.sticklr > li > a .sticky-SA{

    color: #5cb85c !important;
    text-decoration: none !important;
}
.sticklr > li > a .sticky-AF{

    color: silver !important;
    text-decoration: none !important;
}
```

### Result

[image]

Comment: `a.sticky-AS` remove space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take `.sticklr > li > a` , it should work.

### [Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qERrQg)

Answer (score 0):

remove space `a .sticky-AS` should be `a.sticky-AS`

```
.sticklr > li > a.sticky-AS {....}
```